# Date not working with count down with jquery.countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clocker').countdown("2018-09-30 01:00:00", function(event) {
      var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;


      $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
      var czas = event.strftime(totalHours + 'H|%M|%S');
      var result = czas.split('|');
      $(this).html(czas);  

      var godziny = result['0'];
      var minuty = result['1'];
      var sekundy = result['2'];

      godziny = godziny.replace("H", "");
      godziny = godziny.replace("h", "");

      $('.modata1').html(godziny[0]);
      $('.modata2').html(godziny[1]);
      $('.modata3').html(minuty[0]);
      $('.modata4').html(minuty[1]);
      $('.modata5').html(sekundy[0]);
      $('.modata6').html(sekundy[1]);
    });
  });
```

Countdown counts down from the selected date and time. I downloaded the script from the site:
http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

The problem is that it counts down the hours / minutes / seconds badly.

The script eventually breaks down the date on cells on the page and counts down. Counting as such works correctly, however I have a problem with the calculated date.

The script shows me 24h: xx: xx - where there should be definitely more at the moment.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I can't test the code without html code, I'd be easier if you give all the code or give a example on jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qtecsom1/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added 2 div, modata13 and modata14 (I don't wanna mess with the other classes so I just plus 10 more on number) for your missing blocks which don't show

```
<div class="box2_promocja_godzina_prezentacja">
    <div class="godzina_all">
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata1">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata2">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata13">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata14">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_dwukropek_prezentacja">:</div>
        <div class="godzina_napis">hours</div>
    </div>
    <div class="minuta_all">
        <div class="godzina_precentacja  modata3">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_precentacja  modata4">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_dwukropek_prezentacja">:</div>
        <div class="godzina_napis">min</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sekunda_all">
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata5">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_precentacja modata6">0</div>
        <div class="godzina_dwukropek1_prezentacja">:</div>
        <div class="godzina_napis">sec</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="clocker"></div>
```

Then added 2 line to your JS code

```
$('.clocker').countdown("2018-09-30 01:00:00", function(event) {
      var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;


      $(this).html(event.strftime(totalHours + ' hr %M min %S sec'));
      var czas = event.strftime(totalHours + 'H|%M|%S');
      var result = czas.split('|');
      $(this).html(czas);  

      var godziny = result['0'];
      var minuty = result['1'];
      var sekundy = result['2'];

      godziny = godziny.replace("H", "");
      godziny = godziny.replace("h", "");

      $('.modata1').html(godziny[0]);
      $('.modata2').html(godziny[1]);
      $('.modata13').html(godziny[2]);
      $('.modata14').html(godziny[3]);

      $('.modata3').html(minuty[0]);
      $('.modata4').html(minuty[1]);
      $('.modata5').html(sekundy[0]);
      $('.modata6').html(sekundy[1]);
    });
```

Try this out